# Python BeautifulSoup Regex Filter Not Working

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup, findall

I want content of div class 'hide info-json' whose parent li tags class is 'info-wrap' or 'info-wrap no-meta' but not 'info-wrap hide'.

HTML example:

```html
<li class="info-wrap">
    <div class="hide info-json">
        <p>Content That I Want - JSON Data </p>
    </div>
</li>

<li class="info-wrap hide">
    <div class="hide info-json">
        <p>Content That I Don't Want </p>
    </div>
</li>

<li class="info-wrap no-meta">
    <div class="hide info-json">
        <p>Content That I Want - JSON Data  </p>
    </div>
</li>
```

Here is my code:

```py
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text, "lxml")        
        for divTags in soup.findAll('li', class_ = re.compile('^(?!.*hide).*info-wrap.*$')):
            for infoList in divTags.find_all('div',{'class':'hide info-json'}):
                Curinfo = json.loads(infoList.text)
```

but it returns nothing.

If I check this regex on https://regex101.com/r/8yJ5yI/1, it's working fine. Please help me how to do it.

For me its not mandatory to use regex, all I want is `<p>Content That I Want </p>`

Thank you

Comment: if i use `for divTags in soup.findAll(lambda tag: tag.name == 'li' and tag.get('class') == ['info-wrap']):` it ignores li tags with class `info-wrap no-meta`

Comment: `for divTags in soup.findAll('li'`... read that carefully and then have a look at your HTML again. Makes sense that it returns no matches.

Answer (score 0):

```
import re

html = """<li class="info-wrap">
    <div class="hide info-json">
        <p>Content That I Want - JSON Data </p>
    </div>
</li>

<li class="info-wrap hide">
    <div class="hide info-json">
        <p>Content That I Don't Want </p>
    </div>
</li>

<li class="info-wrap no-meta">
    <div class="hide info-json">
        <p>Content That I Want - JSON Data  </p>
    </div>
</li>"""

l = re.findall(r"""<li\s+class="info-wrap(\s+no-meta)?"\s*>\s*
               <div\s+class="hide\s+info-json"\s*>
               \s*(.*?)\s*
               </div>\s*
               </li>
               """,html, flags=re.VERBOSE|re.IGNORECASE|re.DOTALL)
l = [item[1] for item in l]
print(l)
```

Prints:

```
['<p>Content That I Want - JSON Data </p>', '<p>Content That I Want - JSON Data  </p>']
```

[See Demo](http://ideone.com/Xr2M7b)

Answer (score 0):

Use :not (bs4 4.7.1+) to filter out unwanted class

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

html = '''<li class="info-wrap">
    <div class="hide info-json">
        <p>Content That I Want - JSON Data </p>
    </div>
</li>

<li class="info-wrap hide">
    <div class="hide info-json">
        <p>Content That I Don't Want </p>
    </div>
</li>

<li class="info-wrap no-meta">
    <div class="hide info-json">
        <p>Content That I Want - JSON Data  </p>
    </div>
</li>'''

soup = bs(html, 'lxml')
print([p.text for p in soup.select('.info-wrap:not(.hide) p')])
```